# How to transfer two functions in hugs?

Tags: haskell

I want to make a Haskell module which calculate how many cars `p` and motorcycles `m` are in, when I have the numbers of Wheels `r` and carriage `n` overall.

I have the functions:

```
p = (r - 2p) / n
m = n - ((r-2) / 2))
n = p + m
r = 4p + 2m
```

But how do I have to define this as a Haskell function? 
Is the beginning

```
calculator :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
calculator r n = ...
```

How do I correctly compose the functions `p`, `m`, `n`, `r` to define `calculator`?

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work?

Comment: You do know that you've defined 4 constants that are interdependent and will never terminate if evaluated right?

Comment: This is the 4th Haskell question you've asked of the form "I want X but don't know what to do." While it's nice that people are answering your questions - You really should be trying something yourself. And if you are, it would help if you put in the question what your attempts have been. SO is a programming question and answer site, not a place to request code.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to run into a few problems here, you've left out the multiplication operator in a few places (has to be `2 * p` not `2p`), and all of your variables aren't functions but mutually defined values, your `calculator` function has to start with a lower case letter, and you should use `div` instead of `/` for integers (`/` isn't defined for the `Int` type).  You might want something like:

```
numCars :: Int -> Int -> Int
numCars wheels carriages = undefined {- formula for calculating number of cars -}

numBikes :: Int -> Int -> Int
numBikes wheels carriages = undefined {- formula for calculating number of motorcycles -}

calculator :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
calculator wheels carriages = (numCars wheels carriages, numBikes wheels carriages)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr "Enter the number of wheels:  "
    wStr <- getLine
    putStr "Enter the number of carriages:  "
    cStr <- getLine
    let (cars, bikes) = calculator (read wStr :: Int) (read cStr :: Int)
    putStr "The number of cars is:  "
    print cars
    putStr "The number of bikes is:  "
    print bikes
```